Is the axiom of choice needed to show that every Hamiltonian group is of the form $Q_8 \times A \times B$?
A Hamiltonian group is a non-abelian group all of whose subgroups are normal. The smallest Hamiltonian group is the quaternion group $Q_8$. It is known that a group is a Hamiltonian group if and only if it is isomorphic to the direct product $Q_8 \times A \times B$ where $A$ is a vector space over the field with two elements and $B$ is a periodic abelian group with all elements of odd order, as proven by Baer in his German paper "Situation der Untergruppen und Struktur der Gruppe".
But does this characterization require the axiom of choice? Without AC, not every vector space over the field with two elements (or any other field) needs to have a basis, but a basis of $A$ is not needed to show that $Q_8 \times A \times B$ is Hamiltonian. Indeed, elements of the form $(1, a, b)$ or $(-1, a, b)$ are clearly central (hence equal to all their conjugates), while if $b$ has odd order $n$, then the only conjugate of $(x, a, b)$ other than itself (for $x \in \{i, -i, j, -j, k, -k\}$) is $(-x, a, b)=(x, a, b)^{2n+1}$. This shows that every conjugate of an element of $Q_8 \times A \times B$ is a power of that element, and so every subgroup of $Q_8 \times A \times B$ is normal.
This shows that at least AC is not needed in one direction. For the other direction, let $G$ be a Hamiltonian group. Then, given any two elements $x, y \in G$ that do not commute, the conjugate $yxy^{-1}$ must be of the form $x^n$ for some $n>1$. But then $x$ must also be a power of $x^n$ (i.e., $x=(x^n)^m$ for some $m>1$), and so $x$ must have finite order (dividing $nm-1$). So, every non-central element of $G$ must have finite order. If $x \in G$ is central and $y \in G$ is not central (hence of finite order), then $xy$ is not central and so it must have finite order. But then $(xy)y^{-1}=x$ must also have finite order (since $xy$ commutes with $y^{-1}$, which follows from $x$ commuting with $y$). So, every element of $G$ has finite order. Also, if $x \in G$ has order $2$, then $x$ must be central.
So far, AC still has not yet been used (and probably it will never need to be used at all). Using Zorn's lemma (to find a minimal non-abelian subgroup that would then need to be shown to be isomorphic to $Q_8$) will not work, as the intersection of a chain of non-abelian subgroups could turn out to be abelian. I doubt that Baer actually used AC in his paper, but if not, then the same characterization of Hamiltonian groups would remain correct even without AC. If, on the other hand, Baer did use AC in his paper, then either his argument could be adapted to work without AC or else there could be a Hamiltonian group that is not isomorphic to a direct product of the form $Q_8 \times A \times B$ without AC.
